# Join multiple tables with aggregation in Squeryl

Tags: postgresql, scala, orm, squeryl

I'm trying to join a Card with a Part and left join a summed Stock value to a part (some parts won't have a stock row).

I have the following which I thought would work..

```
def stockPerBase = from(stock)(s => groupBy(s.base) compute(sum(s.quantity)))
def allCardsWithStock = 
    join(cards, parts, stockPerBase.leftOuter)((c,p,s) =>
        on(c.partId === p.id, p.base === s.map(_.key))  
        select(c, p, s.measures))
```

However I get the following error:

```
too many arguments for method on: (table: org.squeryl.Table[A])(declarations: A => Seq[org.squeryl.dsl.ast.BaseColumnAttributeAssignment])Unit
[error] on(c.partId === p.id, p.base === s.map(_.key))
```

Any help on how I can do such a query is greatly apprecited.

Answer (score 2):

The `select` clause should come before the `on` in your query. Try reversing the order of the two clauses and it should work.